# What's the most "phone-like" way to use Twilio on an iphone for outbound calls?

Tags: iphone, voip, twilio

I'm using Twilio in an iphone app.  I'm interested in having a dialer in the iphone make outbound calls through Twilio using a Twilio phone #.

The OpenVBX iphone app from Twilio shows a pretty good implementation, but it's not a true outbound call:  the Twilio actually calls back the iphone.

Are there any more phone-like and less obtrusive ways to do this?  One example - is it possible to have the iphone call a twilio # with tel:// , where the twilio # is redirected on-the-fly to the actual destination?  Even that still causes a dialog to be displayed for the user.  Anything with fewer steps than that?

Or are there other services like Twilio that make this more streamlined?

I am interested both in answers that use 3G / Wifi as data (e.g. a SIP client) as well as answers that use the actual voice connection from the iphone.

Comment: There's no way currently to use Twilio without connecting the two phones over the regular phone lines.

Comment: Yes, i get that.  But I'm still interested in what the most seamless ways to do that are for iphone.  For example, one way I can imagine is to have a mobile app invoke the regular iphone dialer to call a twilio phone #, which is configured to route to its final destination.   I'm interested in any approaches like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client) supports making and receiving calls from web browsers and mobile apps. From your iPhone app you can make calls using the data connection that connect to other clients or traditional phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that announcement recently too.   It looks like they just announced the product I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If your application made an API call to a PHP or .Net application then the server application could make the REST API call to initiate the phone call.  To the mobile phone user there is no dialog - their phone just rings and when they answer it they hear the other end ringing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think that's the same thing the openvbx app does that I referenced above.     It seems there's no less-obtrusive way.  Bummer, but not surprising I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar solution which you can find here http://www.twidial.com - its a dialer interface for twilio that allows you to place calls from an ios (or android) phone by bridging a call to your cell. The neat part is you can choose what Twilio number (or verified callerID) you wish to use... which means you can call from your office phone, remote office, home, even other countries if you like.  Twilio is a fantastic service which opens up a ton of possibilities. If you use something like openvbx for inbound or for that matter just forward the calls to your mobile like this https://twidial.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/forwarding-twilio-to-your-cell/

Good luck to you

Comment: I wish there was a good app for SMS... none of them worked when I just tried.